# How to use cronjobs with python email script?

Tags: python, email, cron

I am new to this, but am trying to learn. With a cronjob does it go in a complete other file or in the script its self? Here is my code if that helps.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXS7d.jpg)

I couldn't put in code with the code example so i did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python code doesn't go in the cron entry.  The cron entry just runs python with your script name as an argument.  For example:

```
# run my script at noon every day
0 12 * * * python /path/to/my/email_script.py
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a crontab file. Or is that all i need

Comment: That's all you need (assuming the cron entry format is the same on your system.)